# Baddata Error when getting date || Spring/AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, spring

I'm new to Spring and permamently getting baddata error when trying to get the current date.

The Code:

Date:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

class GetCurrentDate {

GetCurrentDate(){};

    private Date curr = new Date();
    private String strDateFormat = "hh:mm:ss a";
    private DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(strDateFormat);
    private String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(curr);

    String getCurrentDate(){return formattedDate;}

}
```

Angular:

```
    $scope.getTime = function(){
    $http.get('/document/date').then(function(data){
        console.log("Data: " + data);
        $scope.time = data;
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
    //Get date
    @GetMapping("/document/date")
    public String gDate(){
        GetCurrentDate tempDate = new GetCurrentDate();
        return tempDate.getCurrentDate();
    }
```

Thank you!

EDIT: http://uixdk.com/angular/docs/error/$http/baddata says I have to ride my own response transformer or pass valid JSON data to transformResponse. But I actually dont know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I solved this. Here's my solution:

```
    $scope.getTime = function(){
    $http.get('/document/date', {transformResponse: function(response){
                    return JSON.stringify(response);
                    // JSON.stringify() takes a JavaScript object and transforms it 
                       into a JSON string.
                }
            }).then(function(response){
        $scope.time = response.data;
    }).catch(function(error){console.log(error)});

};
```